# syntax error: operand expected (error token is "<= 43") while loop

Tags: shell, while-loop

```
#! /bin/sh
    set i=1
    set j=1
    while (($i <= 43))
    do
    suwind < looptest_fldr109.su > test$j.su key=tracl min=$i max=$i+5
    susort < test$j.su >Xtest$j.su -tracr
    i=`expr $i+6`
    @ j++
    done
```

Hi; I am trying to run a while loop in csh and I keep getting an error:

syntax error: operand expected (error token is "<= 43").

I am not familiar with shell and I think that may be the seat of my issues. 
Thanks!

Comment: "`#! /bin/sh`" "run [...] in csh" Really?

Comment: Are you running this with `/bin/sh` or `csh`/`tcsh`?

Comment: Um... Your shebang line says `/bin/sh`, you claim to be running a loop in `csh`, but you are using a `bash`-specific `(( ... ))` arithmetic context? Pick one shell and stick to it...

Answer (score 1):

run this command to see what shell are you using:

```
ps -p $$
```

then put the right shell after your fist line `#! /bin/sh` at `sh` place.

I have `bash` and your program works just fine with first line changed to:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

if you have C shell then write this:

```
#! /bin/csh
    set i=1
    set j=1
    while ($i <= 43)
    do
      suwind < looptest_fldr109.su > test$j.su key=tracl min=$i max=$i+5
      susort < test$j.su >Xtest$j.su -tracr
      i=`expr $i+6`
      @ j++
    done
```

Comment: Thanks so much! When i try 'ps -p $$' or even 'echo $SHELL' It returns csh as my shell, and when I change the first line to /csh, my error changes to: '=: No such file or directory'. I am certain that my input file exists, and in the same directory as the program! Have you any more ideas? Thanks again.

Comment: in that case write your while loop like this:
  while ( $j <= 5 ) , i.e. with single parenthesis

Comment: I'm afraid the same error persists, even with single parenthesis. Boy, oh boy.

Comment: well I am sorry, I can't help you more cause I don't have C shell and never programmed on one. Try reading this http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/csh-shell-scripting-loop-example/